# Ionic native file opener 2 error class not found

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I receive error when trying to open a file `Class not found`

.ts

```
open(){
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.fileOpener.open(this.entry.nativeURL, this.attachment.mime).then(() => {
    console.log('file opened')
   }, err => {
    console.log('error open file: ', err)
  });
 });
}
```

`this.entry.nativeURL` is the download result using `File Transfer`

nativeURL: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/someFile.docx`

```
this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.storageDirectory + this.attachment.fileName, trustAllHosts).then((entry) => {
 console.log('entry: ', entry);
 this.entry = entry;
}
```

this.attachment.mime: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

I also tried `application/pdf` for a pdf file , didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working... the problem was in running the app live `--livereload`